# Bad dispatch group Notify placement?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, firebase-storage

I'm using a Dispatch Group to call a function once all values in my dictionary have been iterated through. At the start of each item's block I call `enter()` then call `leave()` at the end. I'm putting the dispatch group's `notify` callback at the end of each item's code block, but I'm wondering if this actually makes the callback be called each time an item finishes instead of after all the items have finished. Here's what I have:

```
for value in snap {
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    let petName = value.key as! String
    self.petsDict[petName] = UIImage()

    // Check if pet's image is cached, otherwise fetch from db
    if let petImg = petName.pngImageInDocumentsFolder() {   // Image is cached
        print("Image is cached \(petName)")
        self.petsDict[petName] = petImg
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    } else {                                                // Image not cached, fetch it
        let imgRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(petName+".png")
        imgRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            } else if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data){
                self.petsDict[petName] = image
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }

        }
    }
    self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        self.loadScrollView()
    })
}
```

Since some of these items would perform synchronously (if their image is cached) I think that the next item's loop wouldn't even start by the time the dispatch group's `leave()` is called, and therefore the `notify` would be called.

Should I instead be putting a separate `enter()` before this for loop starts, then a final `leave()` after all the items loops have at least started, so that their `enters()` are accounted for?

**Edit:** I put a print statement in my callback function and confirmed its being called more than once. I guess I'll go with my solution above unless someone has a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `notify` is inside the loop. It should be after the `for-in` body.

The code works fine:

- if you have all synchronous calls - notify calls immediately - it's okay, your processing has ended
- if you have some asynchronous calls - notify waits till the end of the last one to finish, as you do `enter` per loop item